# Possible to get _all_ rendered text on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm looking to log all the text that gets displayed on my OS X 10.6 machine. e.g. all webpage text (no matter the browser), PDF text (not necessarily the entire PDF, but at very least all the text that was actually viewed), anything I type into emacs, any email I write.

I've looked at the Accessibility API, but it seems to be more about describing function than content - and in any case relies on application developers to have implemented accessibility objects. Is there something lower-level? perhaps I can watch everything that goes through the OS font renderer?

After searching for a while my impression is that Apple doesn't explicitly make this possible, I'm open to any hackish suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to get deep inside the Window Server to have any hope of getting all the text that was written to the screen. I suppose you *could* patch it yourself, but it's hard to see how without source. What you want has obvious nefarious uses so there's hardly going to be a  public API for it.

Just a shot in the dark, but what about turning on Screen Sharing on the 'target' Mac and pointing a modified VNC client at it? I don't know whether text is sent as text over VNC or not, but if it was that might be one place to start. It's effectively giving you a Window Server equivalent that you control.

Comment: Hi Tim, pretty sure the most common VNC protocols (RFB, RDP ..etc) are wholly pixel-based. Interesting ideas though, I know it isn't an easy question - thanks.